# Best way to attack a small e and small m RSA problem?

Tags: rsa

I am working through a series of crypto exercises to learn a bit more about RSA and crypto in general. In the case where one has a small $e$ AND a small m, would it be correct to say that if $m<N^{1/e}$ then we can attack by calculating the $e$-th square of $m^{e}$?

If that is a correct statement, then what would be the best way to approach such an attack practically? Is there a tool that exists? Or would it be better to code a brute force solution in Python?

Apologize for the basic questions - just beginning to dip into crypto. Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this homework? did you read Boneh's [Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf)

Comment: It's more of a self study - but thank you for the link - reading now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, computing the e-th root over the integers should work, since $m^e < N$, so their is no 'wrap around', i.e. $m^e \mod N = m^e$.

As for implementation, if $m$ is not too large, say less than $50$ bits, taking a floating point approximation of the root and rounding should do the trick in python:
`m = int(round(c**(1./e)))`

If not, you do not need to resort to bruteforce search though. One simpler way is to start with the above as an initial integer approximation, and then proceed with a binary search, checking whether $m^e > c$ at each step. (There are most likely better algorithms for integral roots, but this should do the trick quite fast already).

Comment: Thank you! This is incredibly helpful and a great direction to investigate. Much appreciated.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer from @fgrieu, big integer are required, but python integer are big integer ;)

Answer (score 3):

> In the case where one has a small $e$ AND a small $m$, would it be correct to say that if $m<N^{1/e}$ then we can attack by calculating the $e$-th square of $m^{e}$?

Yes, in a textbook RSA context, where ciphertext $c$ for the small $m$ is computed as $c=m^e\bmod N$, that is $c=m^e$ if $m<N^{1/e}$. But in RSA as practiced, either $m$ is large and mostly random ([RSA-KEM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5990)), or a padding step is used ([RSAES-OAEP](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=16) or [RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=23)), so that won't work.

> best way to approach such an attack practically?

We want to determine if the $e$-th root of $c$ is an integer, and in the affirmative calculate it, which will be $m$.

It is needed a tool that can compute exactly with large integers. Python, GP/Pari, Mathematica, [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)… have appropriate built-in types, Java comes with a BigInteger package, and it is possible to create one in any Turing-complete language. Some tools have built-in functions to check/compute exact $e^\text{th}$ root. For others an option is to obtain an approximation using floating point, then [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or the less efficient [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search).